# How to model stylized Hoodie

Tags: modeling

How would you go about modeling a hoodie on a tictac shape model like the image below?

For example I started with a outline with a bezier curve but it just doesn't look good.[image]

Comment: Wow - Dwayne uses Blender - didn‘t know that. He is really multitalented!!

Comment: @Chris what can I say... I'm a multidisciplinary artist

Comment: I'd say it looks good. Maybe it's too thick, but for cartoony look, it looks great - as if you modeled it using plasticine.

Comment: isn't the image the reference image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an idea for this.
It is: the basic shape of a hood is a sphere cut in half  and squashed and stretched into more of an oval shape.  Kind of like an egg cut in half from top to bottom.

You just need to take that primitive mesh shape and add a little detail.

I like to start with an add an extra object add on called Add Mesh:  Extra Objects, I am not sure if it is  there by default but it is definitely free.  This gives you a sphere made out of quads instead of the default sphere.

Then I just take that object, delete the front faces.  Then solidify it, bevel it, and apply those modifiers.  This will make the cloth have a bit of a nice rounded rim.  Then I would add a subdivisions modifier to smooth it out, and maybe sculpt it a bit to add details.

I show all the stages of that in this picture here:[image]